# PHP Error Message - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I keep getting the error

> Trying to get property of non-object

in my PHP code. Here is a snippet of the code where the error is occurring.

This is the line the error log refers to: `$high = $highrow->price;`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
$highresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $code WHERE date=$date AND time=$hour ORDER BY price desc LIMIT 1");
$highrow = $highresult->fetch_object();
$high = $highrow->price;
echo $high." - High<br>";
$hightime = $highrow->time; 
echo $hightime."<br>";
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: SELECT * FROM $code where is $code ?

Comment: Its a part of a function. Its just the snippet that is causing the problem not the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
$highresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $code WHERE date='$date' AND time='$hour' ORDER BY price desc LIMIT 1");
$highrow = $highresult->fetch_object();
$high = $highrow->price;
echo $high." - High<br>";
$hightime = $highrow->time; 
echo $hightime."<br>";
```

Edit your select query as above

> SQL requires single quotes around text values (most database systems
>   will also allow double quotes).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line:

```
$high = $highrow->price;
```

here `$high` is an array of object having, having more then one array in it.
So instead of this line try:

```
$high = $highrow[0]->price;
```

or use

```
foreach($highrow as $data)
{
    echo $data->price;
}
```